# Login Gmail Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Hay alguna manera de loguearse en gmail con python3?
He estado probando usando la libreria smtplib en python 2.7 pero no me funciona.
¿Si hay alguna manera me podrían poner un código de ejemplo?
Gracias

Comment: Posiblemente el problema no esté en el lado python sino en el lado Gmail. Google tiene bastante cuidado con el manejo de contraseñas y los mecanismos con los que te permite autenticarte. Una autenticación "convencional" vía SMTP la considera insegura y te recomienda que para ello uses "claves de aplicación". En tu configuración de seguridad de Google puedes generar una. Después usarías esa clave en vez de tu contraseña para autenticarte con smtplib

Comment: Podrías usar la librería para python del [API de Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) y cómo dice @abulafia tendrías que [generar tu token de autorización](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials).